# How do I add the Apple HealthKit package to my own Package as a dependency?

Tags: ios, swift, package, healthkit

Hello dear fellow developers,
I currently work on a swift package where I need to use HealthKit. I created a standalone package the way Apple recommends you to do on their website. But I don't understand how I can add an apple framework/package to my package. Because it is not possible to use the capabilities tab, since it is not a project, but a package.

I believe that a I need a path or something in the dependencies.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add anything, you just `import HealthKit` and the `api` will be available to you.

Comment: You are correct. I restarted Xcode and now it works